# How Does IIS know the binaries are in the BIN directory? Where is this defined?

Tags: wcf, iis, configuration

IIS WCF web services refer to the .dll in the BIN folder.  What configures this location?

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never had a reason to change it myself, I believe it can be done from the system.web section of your configuration file (CodeSubDirectories property):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.aspx